# SSRS Report Formatting Date time

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

How do I write the vb expression for "mm/yy" of a datetime?

I've tried this with no success

```
=Fields!myValue.Value & Format(Fields!myDateTime.Value,"MM/yy")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what your datatypes are. Assuming `myValue` is numeric abd `myDateTime` is a DateTime type then you will probably need to convert the numeric value to a string.

Something like.

```
=CStr(Fields!myValue.Value) & Format(Fields!myDateTime.Value,"MM/yy")
```

If this does not help, post some sample data, including the datatypes and expected result